# Material UI X Grid: Hidden & Sorted Columns Return to Default on Re-render

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am using Material-UI X Grid in a dynamic UI with data updating at ~1Hz. When the page re-renders with new data, any sorted or hidden columns return to their default, i.e. hidden columns are shown again and the columns re-sort to their default positions. Is there any way to stop this behavior and maintain the state selected by the user? I have searched the API documentation and Material-UI's support pages to no avail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

I received support from the Material UI team and am providing the answer here in case it can help someone else.

The issue was that I needed to maintain the columns prop outside of the component via the `useState()` hook. The basics for what worked for me are included below.

```
function Table(props) {

    const [cols, setCols] = useState([]);
    const [cols_loaded, setColsLoaded] = useState(false);

    if(!cols_loaded){
        setCols(funcToReturnCols());
    }

    const data = {columns: cols, rows: getRows(props)};

    content = <div className="data-table">
                <XGrid
                    {...data}
                    loading={data.rows.length === 0}
                    rowHeight={30}
                    autoHeight={true}
                    disableColumnMenu={true}
                    density={"compact"}
                    components={{
                        Toolbar: GridToolbar,
                      }}
                />
            </div>
     ;

     return content;
}
```

The documentation did in fact have a mention that the columns should be maintained outside of the component and that the intent was for them to only be included once, which is smarter anyways!

https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/

From the link above: "The columns prop should keep the same reference between two renders. The columns are designed to be definitions, to never change once the component is mounted. Otherwise, you take the risk of losing the column width state (if resized). You can create the array outside of the render function or memoize it."